# Property of Hermitian matrix

Tags: matrices, trace

How to prove that the sum of diagonal elements of Hermitian matrix equals to the sum of its eigenvalues?

Thanks much!

Comment: This is actually true for any square matrix but the simplest proof I can think of is via the Jordan normal form, which is a bit messy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** the trace is multiplicative, i.e. $\mbox{Tr}(AB)=\mbox{Tr}(BA)$, as soon as the scalar field (or ring) is commutative. In particular, for every invertible matrix $P$ and every matrix $A$ in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ or $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, we have
$$
\mbox{Tr}\;(PAP^{-1})=\mbox{Tr}\; A.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Any Hermitian matrix can be diagonalised, and then note that $\operatorname{tr}(P^{-1} M P) = \operatorname{tr}(M)$